# Using AWS Firehose without AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I m considering using Firehose to send data from a web application.

Firehose service is exposed through the AWS SDK

The SDK is heavy (aws-sdk-2.5.5.min.js weights 1 Mo). This could increase the load time of the website.

Is this an issue ?
How can it be addressed ?
Is it possible to only load parts of the SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the AWS SDK for JavaScript builder tool [here](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/) to build a smaller version of the SDK with only the service(s) you need.

Comment: Thank you! Is this a common way people us firehose on a browser?

Comment: It is a common way for people to use AWS services in the browser, without the need to load the entire SDK. I don't know that using firehose specifically in a browser is common at all, but this is how you would do it.

Comment: The resulting build is still way to huge

Comment: @Dienow If you don't think this is a good answer, post a new question on this site about the specific problem you are having, and how this solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: @MarkB I don't think that this answer addresses fully the problem of the topic starter. And I'm having absolutely the same problem as the topic starter. Available examples of using Kinesis rely on SDK, which is not suitable for the browser environment. Building SDK with Kinesis support only aleviates the problem but doesn't solve it completely. 270Kb (minified) build is less than 1mb build, but is still way too huge and will increase the load time of the website (which both I and the topic starter try to avoid).